# JS - get MIME type from link

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mime-types

Assuming I ask the client to enter a direct link to a video or audio file, and I want to identify the MIME type of the link, is that possible?
I can not rely on AJAX request and header analysis, as I do not know if the remote server will allow cross-domain requests.
I was thinking of adding a  element and reading its metadata, but I can not find a documention how to detecte MIME type through a video element

Comment: Something like this? https://mediainfo.js.org/

Comment: You can use a proxy that you can trust to avoid CORS issues.

Comment: @AdamAzad Thank you, but this package seems to only support local files, not network files

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros I preferred to do everything on a client side and not involve the server, but apparently there is no other choice. Thank you